# Using v-model in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code:

```
<div v-for="(companion, key) in planForm.companions">        
     <div class="field">
          <label class="label">First Name</label>
          <div class="input-space">
              <input :name="'companion_first_name[' + key + ']'" type="text" v-model="companion.first_name">
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="input-space">
              <input :name="'companion_last_name[' + key + ']'" type="text" v-model="companion.last_name">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

However the data binding refers to all elements. If I change one input field the others are also changed. But in the `name` prop of my input element I get the right keys counting from 0 to the last.

---

How can I achieve that only the corresponding data changes?

This is how my data structure looks like in Chrome Vue Panel:

```
companions:Array[3]
 0:Object
  first_name:"Tester"
  last_name:""
 1:Object
  first_name:"Tester"
  last_name:""
 2:Object
  first_name:"Tester"
  last_name:""
```

Here is a fiddle to better reflect my problem: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tytt2qyz/3/)

Comment: It works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LmcxyquL/3/)

Comment: @Mango add :key in v-for ...https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: @RoyJ Right thank you for the answer that took me a step further to find my problem. I have updated your fiddle to reflect my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/tytt2qyz/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tytt2qyz/3/) you are pushing the same object onto the array every time you add one. So you have multiple copies of the same object instead of new independent elements.

This is similar to Vue's requirement that `data` be a function in components, so that instances of the component don't share the same data object. You can solve your problem the same way: make `companionBlueprint` a method:

```
  methods: {
    companionBlueprint() {
      return {
        id: Math.random(),
        first_name: '',
        last_name: ''
      };
    },
    addCompanion() {
      const vm = this;
      const companionBlueprint = vm.companionBlueprint;

      vm.planForm.companions.push(companionBlueprint());
    }
  }
```

I've added an `id` to use as the `:key` in the `v-for`. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tytt2qyz/10/)

Comment: But now I do not have data binding anymore? That's what I get in the Vue Panel for planForm.companions
`companions:Array[2]
0:ƒ bound companionBlueprint()
1:ƒ bound companionBlueprint()`

Comment: Data binding works as far as I can see. Is there something that isn't working as you expect?

Comment: For some reason I get a `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` but looks like I do exactly the same as in your fiddle.

Comment: You're not referring to the array correctly. Some part of `vm.planForm.companions` is not correct for the way your code is set up.

Comment: Dude thanks a lot! I had a problem in my request where `vm.planForm.companions` came back as undifined. Now everything works perfectly fine :)